# Jest - mocking a node module that requires prior configuration

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, contentful

I am using the Contentful SDK in a React app, which requires configuration for authentication.

I have a `contentfulConfig.js` file like so:

```js
import { createClient } from 'contentful';

export default createClient({
    space: SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
})
```

I then import that configured instance in other files and use the different API methods it exposes, like this:

```js
import contentful from './contentfulConfig';

...

contentful.getEntries(...).then(...)
```

In order to test some components that fetch data through the above, I want to mock the results of some of these API methods, for example `getEntries`.

(My mocking needs are very simple: I just want to mock the resolution / rejection values of these methods).

I have tried different permutations of solutions based on the docs and tutorials, but there are two things tripping me up:

1. The method I want to mock is exposed only after configuring the library
2. `contentful` seems to be a Node.js module and so in some solutions I get a 'failed to get mock metadata' error

What could be a clean and simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like

```
 jest.mock('./contentfulConfig', ()=>({
   ...jest.requireActual('./contentfulConfig'),
   getEntries: jest.fn()
   //other functions you want
}))
```

which will allow you to mock all the functions that you want to test in the library

Comment: This works, thank you. I still need to figure out why - there are so many magical things happening at once, like how this actually "patches" the import that you have to do earlier. I need to understand what's going on with mocking at a more fundamental level before the semantics and syntax of Jest really sink in.